# combobox enter the empty field from csv file in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-canvas

```
enter code here 
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import csv

class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.initialize_user_interface()

def initialize_user_interface(self):
     self.button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Summary", command=self.summary_data)
    self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1)


def summary_data(self):
  n = tk.StringVar(value="choose location")
  summarychoosen = ttk.Combobox(self.root, width = 20, textvariable = n);
  summarychoosen.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="wesn")
  with open('UI_LLD.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        aSummary = row['Summary']
        print(aSummary)
        summarychoosen['values'] = [row['Summary']for row in reader] 

app = Application(tk.Tk())
app.root.mainloop()
```

Issue:

1. Combox is taking the empty cell also. In my application i need only the validate string as combobox list
2. In the list the first entry is invisible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UZ2C.png)

Comment: Use strip to remove the empty strings or just do something like if i == "": continue

Comment: Can you throw some light on why it is not taking first element data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully on the for loop:

```py
for row in reader:
    aSummary = row['Summary'] # read the first line
    print(aSummary)
    # read the remaining lines
    summarychoosen['values'] = [row['Summary']for row in reader]
```

Therefore the first entry is missing in the selection list.

Actually you can just remove the for loop, but keep only the last line in the for loop:

```py
with open('UI_LLD.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    # added "if" to filter out empty lines
    summarychoosen['values'] = [row['Summary'] for row in reader if row['Summary'].strip()]
```